# bypass Yes/No in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

There is a shell script it asks `yes/no` multiple times almost 100 times when I run twice on a server. I'm tired of typing `yes` every time. Is there any way to Run that script just taking yes as a default option.Assume following is my script! FYI, I can not edit my script.
Just I can run it using `./ittp-update.sh`

```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "Do you need to install the necessary compiling tools?"
  select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
case $yn in
    Yes ) sudo apt-get install tools; break;;
    No ) <Here I want to skip to the next step. I originally left it 
          blank and removed the "done" command (after esac command) 
          to do this, but if I choose yes, it skips to the end 
          (where the next "done" command is and ends the script>
esac

echo "Do you need to eidt your configuration?"
select ny in "No" "Yes"; do
   case $ny in
    No ) <what do I put here to skip to the next tag 
         (labeled compile for example purposes); break;;
    Yes ) 
esac
 echo "You have 3 options with how you can edit you config file."
```

....

Comment: Yes! http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes

Comment: To expand on @Ken's comment: `yes | ./ittp-update.sh` will answer `yes` to *all* questions (by entering `yes` followed by a newline over and over).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just need to answer "Yes" to everything, you can use

```
yes Yes | ./ittp-update.sh
```

How this works:

1. The program `yes` prints the string you give it (or "y" if you don't give it anything, since this is the default way to give a positive answer in *nix programs) *repeatedly* on standard output until it receives `SIGPIPE`.
2. The pipe (`|`) connects standard output of the preceding command (`yes`) to the standard input of the following command (`./ittp-update.sh`).
3. When `./ittp-update.sh` finishes, the shell automatically sends `SIGPIPE` to any commands connected to it by pipes (only `yes` in this case).
4. Upon receiving `SIGPIPE`, `yes` exits.

See `man yes` for more information.